# Can't use mail on my server. log says it can't find hostname

Tags: linux, email, postfix, nameserver

Basically the log of postfix says:

```
NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[***.***.***.***]: 450 4.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your hostname, [***.***.***.***]; from=<my@email.com> to=<email@ofmyserver.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-vc0-f172.google.com>
```

I tried to send a test-email to my email address on my server. I am trying to configure the postfix there. But i get this reject-error. I am thinking there might be something wrong with my name-server. Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 1):

looks like you have [reject_unknown_client_hostname](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_unknown_client_hostname) in your restrictions, so your postfix will only accept mail from an IP with proper [FcRDNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward-confirmed_reverse_DNS)

make sure your local DNS resolution is working correctly and if this ok, either fix the reverse DNS configuration of the sending system or remove the reject_unknown_client_hostname restriction from your postfix config

Comment: I am quite new to this subject, so excuse my stupidity. So how do i check if reverse DNS is working and am i on the right track if i think that the problem lies in resolv.conf where my nameservers are specified?

Comment: a dns tutorial isn't gonna fit in a comment - please read the documentation of your linux distro. to get you started: if `dig +short google.com` returns a bunch of ips things aren't that bad already. If that doesn't work, your resolv.conf or resolver is probably borked. to check reverse dns : `dig +short -x <ip>`

Comment: Yep dig +short -x <ip>  didn't work, the host to ip dig went well, yes definitely something with reverse dns.

Answer (score 0):

Is your DNS properly registered?
Run

```
> nslookup -type=mx yourmailserveraddress.com 8.8.8.8
```

Where yourmailserveraddress.com is the domain of your email address so email@ofmyserver.com would be ofmyserver.com

If Non-existent domain error pops up or any other error, it will not work properly.
DNS will need to be set up